# how to execute subquery without declaring XML?

Tags: sql, sql-server

why this query is not executing ??

```html
SELECT [Value] = T.c.value('.','varchar(30)') FROM (SELECT  '<s>'+ REPLACE ((select tag_id+',' from tbl_container_track for xml path('')),',','</s> <s>')+ '</s>').nodes('/s') T(c)
```

But this one is working ?

```html
declare @X xml
SELECT  @X = (SELECT  '<s>'+ REPLACE ((select tag_id+',' from tbl_container_track for xml path('')),',','</s> <s>')+ '</s>')
SELECT [Value] = T.c.value('.','varchar(30)') FROM @X.nodes('/s') T(c)
```

Can some one help me to simplify without declaring @X ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: CAST TO XML Datatype you missed

```
SELECT [Value] = T.c.value('.', 'varchar(30)')
FROM   (SELECT Cast(( '<s>' + Replace ((SELECT tag_id+',' FROM tbl_container_track FOR xml path('')), ',', '</s> <s>')
                      + '</s>' ) AS XML)) AS Data
       CROSS APPLY Data.nodes('/s') T(c)
```

Comment: Give alias name to the column after cast operation

Comment: But time taken to execute is very slow !!

Comment: This sort of XML manipulation is not a fast thing in SQL Server. Using typed XML can help, always beware of using XML like this where you are optimizing for performance.